# Bootstrap navbar toggle button hidden on mobile until scroll (iOS)

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, safari, navbar

I am having some trouble with the bootstrap navbar toggle button in iOS (Safari) on small devices. Everything is working as it should in other browsers, even on small devices like phones and tablets.

When the page is loaded the toggle button is hidden until I scroll the page. After having navigated a few links in the menu everything seems to work as it should. It looks like it is only initially that it does not work.

I have no special CSS or anything, just a navbar with the class navbar-fixed-top.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="nav-main" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li id="startlnk"><a class="startlnk" href="#start" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Start</a></li>
                <li id="aboutuslnk"><a href="#aboutus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Om os</a></li>
                <li id="meetuslnk"><a href="#meetus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Medarbejdere</a></li>
                <li id="productslnk"><a href="#products" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Produkter</a></li>
                <li id="priceslnk"><a href="#prices" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Priser</a></li>
                <li id="footerlnk"><a href="#footer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li style="color:#fff;"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Telefon: 75 72 62 52</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="facebook">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/chamelloungevejle?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg facebook-blue"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why the toggle button is behaving like this in Safari on iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what broke the navbar!

It was this css file https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

I disabled more or less everything one step at a time, uploaded and tested on Safari in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to this is very simple just add this script tag at the top`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`